# Magento 1.9.2.1 upload image issue. Disallowed file format

Tags: magento-1.9

Whenever I try to upload the image, the system throws the error

> Disallowed file format.

I have tried a few solutions but nothing worked.

screenshot

[image]

Comment: Which type of file you upload please tell me.? like what is the extension of your image file.

Comment: Any update @FossMentor .?

Comment: png and jpg files mostly with the resolution max 1000*1000

Answer (score 0):

**You can change the configuration under:**

**System > Configuration > Catalog > Product Image**

I had to change Maximum resolution for upload image to **5000px**.

Then on **Product > Images** I got Maximum width and height dimension for upload image is **5000**.

**Note:-**  Please clean **Cache** after all the above steps

Comment: I have tried the same trick but nothing fruitful. Still getting the same error. Any other possible solution?

Comment: Can you please share you configuration which i posted above like what you changed I need a Screenshot.@FossMentor

Comment: please check the screenshot in the below link.
[link] (https://snipboard.io/9tMsUq.jpg)

Comment: You need to increase your pixel size please change 5000 to 10000px and check.@FossMentor

Comment: Can you please just right click on your image which you trying to upload and go to there property and let me know the pixel for that image.

Comment: Done that even I tried with a large pixel size as well but nothing fruitful.

Comment: I tried with different jpg resolution like 768*1024, 800*1200 or even smaller 72*72

Comment: I can just provide you my TeamViewer access. If you can help me over there it would be great.